# Why it is not redirecting me after login in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, authentication

I have class with the following function:

```
/**
 * Redirect after login to specific page
 */
public function redirect_after_login( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    $pageURL = self::$plugin_settings['wp_redirect_to_custom_page'];
    $redirect_to = $pageURL;
    return $redirect_to;
}
```

and in my constructor is the filter:

```
add_filter( 'login_redirect', array( $this, 'redirect_after_login' ), 10, 3 );
```

The problem is that the function doesn't redirect me without to throw any exceptions. I'm just signing in to default page. If i `var_dump($redirect_to)`
it shows the right url which is

```
https://facebook.com
```

For example. Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I change the function to:

```
public function redirect_after_login( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    $redirect_to = self::$plugin_settings['wp_redirect_to_custom_page'];

    return $redirect_to;
}
```

and currently is working :)